# Problema apresentação de textos no php com editor tinymce

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

Tenho um gestor com o editor HTML *tinymce*, mas cada vez que insiro uma informação no banco, ao apresentar na página através do PHP o texto aparece sem parágrafos e com algumas *tags* estanhas não sei por que acontece isto.

[image: SS]

Como podem ver na imagem aparece essas *tags* que por si aparecem também na página quando chamo por PHP a visualização do conteúdo.

Comment: Eu usava esse componente, mais achei um muito melhor e mais facil de implementar.
olhe se goste: http://www.sceditor.com/

Comment: Vou analisar a sugestão.obrigado

Comment: Ok, certeza que vai gostar mais.

Answer (score 1):

Bem pessoal entretanto consegui resolver reparei que tinha uma problema de configuração do editor comparado as fonts que tinha adicionado acabei a resolver com o seguinte código deixo para se alguém passar por o mesmo problema.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.editme",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
</script>
```

Isso vai activar todas as funções do editor // NOTA E PARA A VERSÃO 4 DO EDITOR